# standardise independent variables and prediction

Tags: regression, standardization

I standardized some of my independent variables and ran a linear regression. However, I want to use the coefficient from the input data to predict other sample. But I am not sure how should I standardize the new sample. Thanks.

Comment: You use the same standard deviation and mean as the one used for the training of your model.

Answer (score 0):

Anything you do to the training data, do the same to the testing data.

Let’s say you calculated your standardized variable by subtracting the mean of the training data, $8$, and dividing by the variance of the training data, $3$.

In your new data, you observe a mean of $7$ and a standard deviation of $4$.

You still do the standardization with $8$ and $3$, **not** with $7$ and $4$.

Ideas like this come up all the time where there’s some transformation determined by the training data and it would be a slightly different transformation if you determined the transformation with the testing data. Perhaps with (very) rare exceptions, you always do the transformation based on the training data.